# error in csv file from comma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I installed the comma gem today and everything worked perfectly, but the actual .csv file is empty except for the first cell, which reads:

```
#<Proc:0x2795700@C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/comma-0.4.1/lib/comma/render_as_csv.rb:35>
```

I'm calling comma with this in my controller:

```
def index
  @registrants = @rsvp.rsvp_registrants

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { render :csv => @registrants }
  end
end
```

And keeping it simple in my model for now:

```
comma do
  email
end
```

I have tried various other queries, including ones that only return one record, just for troubleshooting purposes. Also installed fasterCSV just now in case it was a dependency.

I'm on Rails 3, Ruby 1.9.2, developing on a Windows XP machine.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the [latest version of comma](http://rubygems.org/gems/comma)(0.4.1) is missing [this patch to fix Rails3 rendering support](https://github.com/crafterm/comma/pull/15) which seems like it would fix the problem you are experiencing.

Try using comma from github instead

```
gem "comma", :git => "git://github.com/crafterm/comma.git"
```

Comment: that line threw an error. Windows issue maybe? Any thoughts? Thanks @Christopher.

Comment: @Brett I do believe you need git installed to make this work: http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/ and make sure to select `Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt`